# Why does a const char* cast to std::string work?

Tags: c++

This cast puzzles me:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str1 =  (string)"I cast this thing" +  " -- then add this";
    cout << str1 << endl;
}
```

Can someone explain why this c-style cast to string works (or is allowed)? I compared the generated optimized assembly with that from:

```
string str1 =  string("I construct this thing") +  " -- then add this";
```

and they appear to be identical, so I feel like I'm forgetting some c++ semantics that actually allow this kind of cast/construction to be interchanged.

```
 std::string str2 =  std::string("I construct this thing") +  " -- then add this";
```

Comment: `(T)x` = `T(x)`. The two are **identical** except in name (C-style cast vs function-style cast).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A C-style cast will do a const cast and static cast or reinterpret cast whichever is possible.

A static cast will use a user-defined conversion if defined.

`std::string` has a constructor `string(const char *)`.

The syntaxes `std::string("something")`, `static_cast<std::string>("something")` and `(std::string)"something"` are equivalent. They will all construct a temporary `std::string` using the `std::string::string(const char *)` constructor. The only difference between the syntaxes would be when casting pointers.

Comment: makes complete sense...for some reason I always forget about the "valid user defined conversions" with respect to static casting.

Answer (score 7):

Yep, if you have a constructor that takes in a single argument like that it will be used to cast the argument type to the object type. This is why we can pass `const char*` to functions taking strings.

[Converting constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor)

Answer (score 4):

[`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) has a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) in the form of

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

This acts as a conversion operator.  If you cast a string literal to a `std::string` it will call this constructor and create a temporary `std::string`